# Adsense TOS regarding preconnecting origins

Tags: html, google-adsense, performance, google-adsense-policies

Is it against adsense TOS if I preconnect origins like *pagead2.googlesyndication.com*, *googleads.g.doubleclick.net*, *tpc.googlesyndication.com* and others that are commonly used by adsense?

The implementation will be like this:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly fine to do. web.dev, a Google project, recommends doing exactly that at https://web.dev/uses-rel-preconnect/.